# Why we need two times write handlers in tomcat logging.properties?

Tags: java, tomcat, properties, logging

From [docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html):

```
handlers  = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
            2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
            3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
            java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
            java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

I didn't found any explanation why need write `handlers` and after `.handlers`?

Are there common rules for similar properties files?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The first line declares the set of handlers that can/will be used, the second one assigns handlers to the specific logger (in this case root logger as `.handlers` is not prefixed with anything).

Later on in `logging.properties` each handler is configured.

Answer (score 37):

To expand on [soulcheck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9140170/516188), which I didn't understand at first...

The `handlers = ...` line can be seen as a "variable declaration".

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
       2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
       3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
       java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

"I declare a logger of name `1catalina` and type `FileHandler`, a logger of name `2localhost` and type `FileHandler`.. a logger of type `ConsoleHandler` (not naming the last one since there's only one, so no ambiguity)."

On the other hand, the `.handlers` line would be an "assignment".

```
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 
       java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

"I assign the 1catalina & console handlers to the root logger. Which means any logging done in the application at all will be forwarded to these handlers (unless overriden)"

The `.` in `.handlers` refers to what you're applying that on. In this case, since there's nothing on the left of the `.`, you're applying it to the root logger, which all loggers inherit from.

But this is exactly the same principle in action in this line:

```
com.mycompany.MyClass.handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

In this case there is something on the left of the `.` for the `.handlers` and that means we don't assign these handlers to the root logger but to a specific logger. With this line you say "I'm overwriting the standard logger->handler assignment for this specific logger. In this case, don't act like you would based on the root logger configuration. In this case, I want you to use only the `ConsoleHandler` for that logger".

So that means that any logging for `MyClass` will be sent only to the `ConsoleHandler` and not to any other handler. The other classes are no affected by this line.

Again I'm just repeating the explanation from soulcheck, but in more detail, which I needed myself to understand the difference.

Comment: Your explanation of the '.handlers' part is really good. Now it makes more sense to me.