# sending errors and exceptions through emails in apache tomcat server start

Tags: java, xml, apache, tomcat, logging

I have used apache-tomcat-7.0.25 and started a local instance on my system.
i have to send errors and exceptions through emails to various people which i have found in the log files.
i have the config files server.xml , web.xml, tomcat-users.xml , context.xml , catalina.properties files and also a logging.properties file.

the logging.properties file consists of the following code.

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
           2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
           3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
           java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.bufferSize = 16384

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter


############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = \
   2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = \
   3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

# For example, set the org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase logger to log
# each component that extends LifecycleBase changing state:
#org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.level = FINE
```

How to redirect it to a mail when there is any error or exceptions?

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer:** I'm a content developer for [MailHandler](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/CHANGES.txt) included with JavaMail project.

For `java.util.logging` you can use [MailHandler](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/util/logging/package-summary.html) included with [JavaMail](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/).

1. Download the [JavaMail](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release) reference implementation jar file (javax.mail.jar).
2. [Modify the tomcat startup script include JavaMail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590330/custom-java-util-logging-handler-in-tomcat) in the Tomcat bootstrap ClassLoader.
3. [Modify the logging.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139908/why-we-need-two-times-write-handlers-in-tomcat-logging-properties) file to install the MailHandler and any supporting classes.

Here is a sample configuration:

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler


com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.subject=com.sun.mail.util.logging.CollectorFormatter
#com.sun.mail.util.logging.CollectorFormatter.format=Tomcat:{0}{1}{2}{4,choice,-1#|0#|0<... {4,number,integer} more}
#com.sun.mail.util.logging.CompactFormatter.format=[%4$-7.7s] %7$#.140s
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.level=WARNING
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.filter=com.sun.mail.util.logging.DurationFilter
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.pushLevel=WARNING
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.mail.host=some-smtp-host
#com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.mail.user=some-user
#com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.authenticator=some-password
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.mail.from=app@server.com
#com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.mail.sender=team@list.com
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.mail.to=devs@bugfixers.com
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.verify=resolve
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.mail.smtp.quitwait=false
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.mail.smtps.quitwait=false
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=45000
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.mail.smtps.connectiontimeout=45000
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.mail.smtp.timeout=45000
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.mail.smtps.timeout=45000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `log4j` for this via [SMTPAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SMTPAppender.html)

Sample configuration would look like:

```
log4j.rootLogger= , mail, .. more appenders ..

#Email Appender
log4j.appender.mail=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.mail.BufferSize=1
log4j.appender.mail.SMTPHost=smtp.serverhere.com
log4j.appender.mail.From=FROMEmailAddress
log4j.appender.mail.To=List of recipients
log4j.appender.mail.Subject=Application Error
log4j.appender.mail.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.mail.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.mail.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - <%m>%n
```