# How can I make the log rotation work in Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, java.util.logging

I just made changes in `conf/logging.properties` to rotate a log file after a specific time. However, it is not working.

Changes look like:

```
#.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler



#1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
#1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
#1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.
1catalina.java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = FINE 
1catalina.java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = ${catalina.base}/logs/catalina.%g.log 
1catalina.java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 13107200 
1catalina.java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 5 
1catalina.java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter =  java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

Comment: Provide more detail.  What are trying to do? What do you expect to happen?  What is happening instead?  The [java.util.logging.FileHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html) rotates by file size not time.

Comment: I'm trying to rotate catalina.out file which eventually grows too large on the server. Gist is if size becomes 1GB, catalina.out gets rotated without tomcat service restart. I dont want to use OS logrotate since it's not working as expected in our setup.  With the above changes nothing is working.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are confusing the [org.apache.juli.FileHandler](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/juli/FileHandler.html) and the [java.util.logging.FileHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html).

From the config file you are wanting to use the `java.util.logging.FileHandler` [so you need to install that handler on the logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139908/why-we-need-two-times-write-handlers-in-tomcat-logging-properties).

```
handlers = 1catalina.java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.handlers = 1catalina.java.util.logging.FileHandler

1catalina.java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = FINE 
1catalina.java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = ${catalina.base}/logs/catalina.%g.log 
1catalina.java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 13107200 
1catalina.java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 5 
1catalina.java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter =  java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

The other option is to use the tomcat FileHandler:

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina. 
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.rotatable = true 
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.formatter =  java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

Comment: I did try your suggestion also, however it didn't work

Comment: Same here - Tomcat 7.0.22

Comment: @JackTheKnife You might want to open a new question.  That way you can post your log config and any other debugging information.  This question confuses rotation by time vs. rotation by size.

Comment: @jmehrens Yup, I have already did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49322523/tomcat-logging-properties-formatter-not-taking-effect