# Backup log files before creating new logs using tomcat server.xml or web.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

I am working on a Java application where I am writing info and error logger to a text file as log for our reference. That file is growing enormously, so I need to check for the size of the file... For example, if the file size crosses 10 Mb, I have to create another file.

Like this, I have to create 10 files, rotating one after the other until ten files. After reaching ten files, I have to delete the starting files and start creating again...

How can I delete files after the no. of files will become 10?

The main constraint in this action is trying to complete the requirement without using log4j or logback libraries.

Logging.properties

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter


############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler
```

Comment: Are you using third-party APIs like log4j?

Comment: Even if you do not want to use log4j, you can have a look at its source: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.15/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.java

Comment: Include some of your logging code and or configuration file.

Comment: @jmehrens Included the snippet for logging.properties

Answer (score 0):

Given your constraints, you can use the [java.util.logging.FileHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html) instead of the `org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler`.

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 10000000
2localhost.java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 10
2localhost.java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = ${catalina.base}/logs/localhost%g.log

3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter


############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler
```

You'll have to [modify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139908/why-we-need-two-times-write-handlers-in-tomcat-logging-properties) the logging.properties so you can install the JUL FileHandler.