# Explanation of Tomcat JULI logging.properties

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, configuration

I normally use Log4J. I am trying to understand how JULI is configured in the Tomcat server. I have provided my understanding of what these lines mean starting with the character *. Can you please make sure my understanding is correct please.

```
 *THE SET OF ALL HANDLERS HAVE TO BE DECLARED AS VALUES OF handlers
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler,2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

 *THIS IS THE SET OF HANDLERS ALL LOGGERS WILL HAVE THESE HANDLERS like rootLogger IN LOG4J. YOU DO NOT HAVE DECLARE THEM FOR ANY LOGGERS.
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

 *THIS IS THE CONFIGURATION FOR ALL THE HANDLERS
############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter =        java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################
 *[localhost].handlers IS THE SPECIFIC HANDLER FOR LOCALHOST 
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

# For example, set the com.xyz.foo logger to only log SEVERE
# messages:
#org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.level = FINE
#org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.level = FINE
#org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.level = FINE
#org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.level=FINE
```

I am confused by this line:
    .handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

Does every logger get these two loggers even if they have declared their own loggers? So when a message is logged to 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler it also logged to 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler and java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.

Or if a logger has its handlers set, logging will not occur on 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler because its handlers are set.

Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

The [Logging in Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html) documentation will answer your questions.

> I am confused by this line: .handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
>
> Does every logger get these two loggers even if they have declared their own loggers? So when a message is logged to 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler it also logged to 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler and java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.

Per the documentation page above:

> A prefix may be added to handler names, so that multiple handlers of a single class may be instantiated. A prefix is a String which starts with a digit, and ends with '.'. For example, 22foobar. is a valid prefix.

The standard JUL `LogManager` doesn't support multiple configurations per a single class name.  By adding the prefix it allows JULI to create multiple instances of the same class type with different configurations from the `logging.properties`.

So going back to your example config file in your question, `1catalina.` and `2localhost.` are just prefix identifiers to create a `org.apache.juli.FileHandler` with a specific configuration.

> I am interested on the ".handlers" entry in the properties file. Do you know what the "." character does?

For Tomcat, this is explained in: [Why we need two times write handlers in tomcat logging.properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139908/why-we-need-two-times-write-handlers-in-tomcat-logging-properties)